# Office365 + Email Gateway DKIM setup

Tags: networking, email, firewall, office365

I plan on implementing a secure email gateway to scan inbound and outbound messages before they are delivered to Office365.

Currently outbound messages are signed using DKIM on 365
The email gateway software supports signing messages outbound using DKIM

Would I need to disable DKIM on 365 and enable DKIM on the gateway or should it be enabled on both?